# Opening and sorting huge files

Tags: microsoft-excel, spreadsheet

I am working with huge files like 2.000.000.000 rows. I need this file to be sorted, maybe filtered an so on.

Can you recommend me a software? Preferably on Linux, but can be in any OS.

I am looking for a free software but willing to buy it too depending on the performance of course.

Comment: Can you expand on what you mean by sorting?

Comment: Do you mean [XLS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Excel#File_formats) files? Or CSV? Or …?

Comment: And what do you need to sort on? And if you need filtering: how/what? You really should pay more attention to writing a good question (if you want answers instead of counter-questions).

Answer (score 1):

For large file support, sorting, filtering, ect., you will be very hard pushed to beat [Pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/).

- Can read & write numerous formats including CSV, Excel & HDF.
- Free, Gratis & Open Source
- Cross Platform including Linux, Windows & OS-X
- Fast & Powerful

Worth a look: There is also [PyTables](http://www.pytables.org/) which uses [HDF5](http://hdfgroup.org/HDF5/) for managing hierarchical data sets and has been bench marked performing data lookup in 10 gigarow 10^10 rows in under 0.1 seconds.